# To make html form run two actions

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit, input-type-file

Is it possible to submit two forms using a single submit button?

like if a user clicks submit on a form, that form runs `test.php` and `form.php` with the variables still intact?

If not then is it possible when the user clicks submit on a form it runs only `test.php` then `test.php` runs `form.php` with the variables still intact.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible on a normal form submission, but you can try to utilize an AJAX request on both forms on demand. (This is just an example, not tested, just a guide or an idea.).

```
<!-- forms -->
<fieldset><legend>Form #1</legend>
    <form id="form_1" action="test.php">
        <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></label>
        <label>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></label>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<br/>
<fieldset><legend>Form #2</legend>
    <form id="form_2" action="form.php">
        <label>Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /></label>
        <label>Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /></label>
    </form>
</fieldset>

<button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
<!-- the forms is just an example -->
<!-- it would be weird to separate such fields in to different forms -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').on('click', function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: $('#form_1').attr('action'),
            data: $('#form_1').serialize(),
            type: 'POST', // or whatever get
            dataType: 'JSON', // or whatever xml script html
            success: function(response) {

            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: $('#form_2').attr('action'),
            data: $('#form_2').serialize(),
            type: 'POST', // or whatever get
            dataType: 'JSON', // or whatever xml script html
            success: function(response) {

            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form can have only one action, if you want to pass data to a different page then you can do that by calling an ajax function..